# GROUP BY - выполнить сортировку внутри группы

Tags: mysql

При выполнении группировки

```
GROUP BY
```

Каким образом указывается сортировка?
В данный момент, группируется и берется первая строка. А что если необходима последняя строка в группе?

```
id list  name
1   0    name1 
2   1    name2
3   3    name3
4   1    name4
5   3    name5
6   0    name6

На выходе необходимо получить

id list  name
6   0    name6
5   3    name5
4   1    name4
1   0    name1

SELECT * FROM news GROUP BY IF(list=0, -id, list) HAVING MAX(id) ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: Сортировка и группировка - два совершенно несвязанных этапа, к тому же между ними ещё есть этап пост-отбора. Полагаю, что имеется в виду синтаксически ошибочный запрос, который выполняется в рамках расширения при отключенном ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. *и берется первая строка.* Не "первая", а "первая попавшаяся". Причём при двух последовательных запусках может попасться как одна и та же, запись, так и разные.

Comment: Применяю следующее выражение GROUP BY IF(n.list=0, -n.id, n.list)

Comment: То есть группирую те записи чья ячейка list не равна 0. Выхватывается первая строчка в группе, для остальных же применяется ORDER BY time_add DESC.  Сортирует верно, но в группе по прежнему берется первая строчка. Как быть?

Comment: GROUP BY IF(n.list=0, -n.id, n.list) HAVING MAX(n.id)  Не помогает...

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ПОЛНЫЙ текст запроса.

Comment: Добавил то как это дела.  В моем запросе еще 3 таблицы подключено, в примере только на одной. Не проверял, но работать должен. Там еще есть WHERE, выборка, если не ошибаюсь она перед группировкой должна быть. Если запрос с ошибкой, возможно в этом дело.

Comment: Укажите **точно** версию MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рассмотрим ту же проблему на более простом примере.

Имеется таблица:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test (a INT, b INT);
INSERT INTO test VALUES (1,1), (1,2);
```

Выполняется запрос:

```sql
SELECT a, b
FROM test
GROUP BY a;
```

Мы требуем группировку по `a`. То есть в результате мы должны получить одну запись для каждого значения этого поля в исходной таблице, сколько бы раз оно там не присутствовало. На показанных данных в таблице такое значение одно - единица, и встречается оно дважды - то есть на выходе получится одна запись, и в поле `a` будет единица.

Но что будет в результате поле `b`? Исходных записей - две, там значения один и два. Что вернуть? какое из этих значений выбрать? и почему? текст запроса на эти вопросы ответов не даёт... А сервер - он не будет проявлять инициативу и выбирать одно из имеющихся значений "от фонаря". Он просто сообщит, что условие выбора недоопределено. И сообщит это, выдав сообщение об ошибке.

Для того, чтобы запрос был корректен, любое поле выходного набора, которое не указано в выражении группировки, должно быть аргументом агрегатной функции. Например, так:

```sql
SELECT a, MAX(b) AS b
FROM test
GROUP BY a;
```

В этом случае у сервера нет никакой неопределённости. Ему чётко сказано, что в поле `b` надо поместить максимальное из имеющихся значений. И он из имеющихся значений со спокойной душой вернёт двойку.

---

Кроме указанной ошибки, запрос в вопросе ещё содержит и логическую избыточность. В нём используется условие пост-отбора `HAVING MAX(id)`. Оно будет истинно, если значение  `MAX(id)` будет не ноль и не NULL. А поскольку (ну во всяком случае чисто визуально) все значения в поле `id` больше нуля и не NULL, то все результирующие записи будут в этом условии давать истину. То есть это условие вообще можно удалить - оно не влияет на результат.

Comment: Условие влияет, если просто сгруппировать по значению поля. То он сгруппирует все, но нам та необходимо сгруппировать те записи поле 'list' которого не равен нулю. Если поле содержит 0, то данную запись не группируем вместе с остальными.

Comment: Завтра буде пытаться дальше пробовать. Вопрос тако если указывать max(b), если данное поле не содержит число, значение его строчка. Как в таком случаи он выхватит последюю. По длине строчки, это не выход...

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов *если указывать max(b), если данное поле не содержит число, значение его строчка. Как в таком случаи он выхватит последюю. По длине строчки* о_О Это с какого такого перепугу-то? Вам знаком такой термин как "лексикографический порядок"?